# How to specifiy the number of repetitions of a regex pattern

Tags: regex, syntax

I have a sentence, for example the following:

Diesmal geht es um den Genitiv nach Präpositionen am Beispiel von "wegen": Wegen des Sturmes oder wegen dem Sturm?

In this sentence I want to match the word am, about in the middle of the sentence. However, I also want to match 5 words after and before this word. My regex for doing so is the following:

```
.+?\s+.+?\s+.+?\s+.+?\s+.+?am.+?\s+.+?\s+.+?\s+.+?\s+.+?\s+
```

But this looks quite clumsy. My question is whethere there is a way to specify the number of repetitions of the .+?\s+ part. Can anyone please help me here? I use PHP for this purpose.

Comment: what coding language are you using?

Comment: I try to do this in a PHP program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use curly braces for that:

```
a{2}   // two a's
a{1,}  // one or more a's
a{1,3} // between 1 and 3 a's
```

Use parentheses for complex patterns:

```
(foo){2,3} // two or three foo's
```

[Read more about repetitions in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: The parentheses were the part I got wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`{#}` repeats the last item # times. So `(\s+.+?){3}` is equivalent to `\s+.+?\s+.+?\s+.+?`

So you would use `(.+?\s+){5}am(.+?\s+){5}`